# Which Canon flatbed scanners are supported in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, canon, scanner

How do I find out which Canon flatbed scanners are supported in Ubuntu 12.04?

Specifically I need to know if the **Canon LiDE 110** is supported?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Ubuntu HardwareSupport wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/). You find a [list of Canon scanners](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon) there, but the one you mentioned is not listed there - which does not automatically mean that it wouldn't run, though.

On [this (German) weblog](http://www.finnchristiansen.de/?p=557) I read that Ubuntu supports Canon LiDE 110 since 11.04 - so it should run.